What should be the proper XCM format?
I'm not sure if these are the right questions to ask, as I'm pretty new to the world of Cross-Consensus Messaging (XCM), but I'm really curious about how to properly create XCM instructions or an XCM format.
For instance, I want to transfer my asset balances from Polkadot/Kusama AssetHub to my Parachain and vice versa. What should be the proper XCM format, or what are the instructions that should be used? Does it have to be in a specific order, like do we need to use the WithdrawAsset instruction first and then BuyExecution?
Additionally, where does the XCM need to be executed? Does it have to be in AssetHub or in my Parachain?
Lastly, when do we need to use V2, V3, and V4?
I apologize for asking too many questions, but if someone could provide details or guidelines, it would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

You can find xcm information here: https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/

@Purple_Turtle Thank you!
